# Plot multiple variables, with time series

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a dataframe where the first column has different types of bacteria, and the rest of the columns the samples, each sample belong to a specific time (T0, T1...) and the last 39 columns are  the control group.

What I pretend is to plot each bacteria in one plot. And the plot must contain the different times in x-axis and the value in the y-axis (I was thinking in a bar plot or box plot with the errors coef.

Any idea about how can I group the data for different times and for different bacteria?

Here a small example of the data:

thanks!

```
structure(list(Bacteria = c("Methanobrevibacter", "Methanosphaera", 
"Methanomassiliicoccus"), PIE2001_T0_TORUNDA = c(2.279974027, 
0.670536115, -0.022611066), PIE2001_T1_TORUNDA = c(2.021643324, 
-0.057798217, -0.057798217), PIE2001_T5_COMPL = c(2.788566988, 
0.648500825, -0.044646356), PIE2006_T0_TORUNDA = c(0.07550014, 
1.684938052, 0.07550014), PIE2007_T0_TORUNDA = c(2.072075243, 
1.261145027, -0.125149334), PIE2007_T1_TORUNDA = c(2.601582257, 
1.279826417, -0.106467944), PIE2007_T2 = c(2.81564899, 1.765826865, 
-0.180083284), PIE2007_T3 = c(0.639040509, 3.081387545, -0.054106671
), PIE2013_T0_COMPLETA = c(2.683794403, -0.024255798, -0.024255798
), PIE2013_T1_COMPLETA = c(2.614756053, -0.024301277, -0.024301277
), PIE2013_T4_COMP = c(2.653056483, 0.013999154, 0.013999154), 
    PIE2013_T5_COMPL = c(1.861263144, -0.084647005, -0.084647005
    ), PIE2014_COMP = c(2.304771706, 1.005488722, -0.093123567
    ), PIE2016_T0_COMPLETA = c(-0.141271428, -0.141271428, -0.141271428
    ), PIE2016_T1_COMPLETA = c(-0.081696055, -0.081696055, -0.081696055
    ), PIE2016_T3 = c(-0.019385468, -0.019385468, -0.019385468
    ), PIE2016_T3_TOR = c(0.045856809, 0.045856809, 0.045856809
    ), PIE2017_T0_COMPLETA = c(4.493506636, 0.189441543, 0.189441543
    ), PIE2017_T1_COMPLETA = c(5.001671041, 0.71808448, 0.024937299
    ), PIE2017_T2_TOR = c(5.887191114, 0.672255357, -0.020891824
    ), PIE2017_T3 = c(3.306066839, 0.703377154, 0.010229973), 
    PIE2017_T4_COMP = c(5.560847286, 1.371192544, -0.015101817
    ), PIE2017_T5_COMPL = c(5.688626959, -0.025105846, -0.025105846
    ), PIE2018_T1 = c(0.158551089, 0.158551089, 0.158551089), 
    PIE2019_T1_COMPL = c(6.659430141, 0.833430034, 0.140282853
    )), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Script updated:

```
colnames(df)[363:401] <- gsub("T0", "T6", colnames(df)[363:401])  
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Bacteria) %>%
  mutate(group = gsub('_.*$', '', name),
         time = gsub('^.*_(T\\d+).*$', '\\1', name)) %>%
  filter(grepl('T\\d+', time)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, value, fill = Bacteria)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'summary', fun = 'mean', position = 'dodge') +
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_se", geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_grid(Bacteria ~ ., scale = 'free_y') +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = 'gray75'))
```

[image]

Comment: In addition to T0, T1, etc, your columns include years and different suffixes. Should this information be considered in structuring the plot, and if so how?

Comment: Only the different time-series, the other information can be excluded. The example that I have given is a little part of a huge dataframe, the last 39 columns belong the control group but they have also T0 as sufix

Answer (score 2):

Pivot your data to long format, then facet by bacterium:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)

dat_long <- dat %>%
  pivot_longer(!Bacteria, names_to = "sample") %>%
  mutate(sample = fct_inorder(sample)) 
  
ggplot(dat_long, aes(sample, value)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(vars(Bacteria), ncol = 1) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Or make a line graph with bacteria mapped to `color`:

```
ggplot(dat_long, aes(sample, value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Bacteria, group = Bacteria)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: The geom_col() output is was I expected, but grouped as @Allan Cameron has posted. when I tried, I get different scales and I do not know why

Comment: Do you get what you want if use Allan’s data prep with my plot specification, then?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by "I get different scales." You could try adding or removing the `scales = "free_y"` argument.

Comment: Thanks! I have just update the script with a clarification

Answer (score 2):

You need to reshape your data. You can then do a comparative boxplot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Bacteria) %>%
  mutate(group = gsub('_.*$', '', name),
         time = gsub('^.*_(T\\d+).*$', '\\1', name)) %>%
  filter(grepl('T\\d+', time)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, value, fill = Bacteria)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_grid(Bacteria ~ ., scale = 'free_y') +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set2') +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = 'gray75'))
```

[image]

Comment: That is what I was looking for, but as I have mentioned, the last 39columns are the control group, should I rename the last columns maybe because the have T0 as sufix?

Comment: I have used `colnames(tgbias1)[363:401] <- gsub("T0", "T6", colnames(tgbias1)[363:401])`, but how could I modified your script to detect "control" as other "time"? 
Also I will get 9 plots, is it possible to separate in a grid 3x3 (for example)? (I've tried with `facet_wrap(~Bacteria, ncol = 3, scales = 'free_y')`, but it didn't work) Thanks!